# Ramanujan-type identity $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{e^{2^{-k}n\pi}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}16^{n-1}$

Tags: integration

On [my previous page on Ramanujan's-type identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784947/a-ramanujan-type-identity-11-sum-n-1-infty-fracn3e2n-pi-1-16-sum) Jack D'Aurizio and Paramanand Singh independently offered their own method of proving that beautiful identity. I am greatly appreciated for their efforts in proving the identity.

Here we offered two Ramanujan-type identities with its closed form; we have found them during own intensive search using the sum calculator. **We need anyone to verify it correctness, thank you.**

(1)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{e^{2^{-k}n\pi}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}16^{n-1}$$

(2)

$$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^7}{e^{2^{-k}n\pi}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{2k+1}16^{n-1}$$

**I just wonder is there one for the 11?**

$$f(n,k)=\sum_{n=0}^{f(k)}11^{n-1}$$

Comment: $(1)$ does not hold. For instance, $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^3}{e^{n\pi/2}-1}=1.0625000031133585\ldots\neq 1+\frac{1}{16}.$$

Comment: By Abel-Plana's formula your RHS is just the main term of the series, but a small remainder depending on the square of an elliptic integral is still there.

Comment: Also see (23) and (24) on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EisensteinSeries.html .

Comment: Thank you @JackD'Aurizio I am going to investigate to see if I can modify.

Comment: Maybe it could help $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{k^3}{e^{\pi  k 1/2}-1}=-\frac{-128 \pi ^2 \left(\psi _{e^{4 \pi }}^{(1)}(1)-\psi _{e^{8 \pi }}^{(1)}(1)+\psi _{e^{4 \pi }}^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{i}{4}\right)\right)+2 \psi _{e^{4 \pi }}^{(3)}(1)+\psi _{e^{8 \pi }}^{(3)}(1)+2 \psi _{e^{4 \pi }}^{(3)}\left(1-\frac{i}{4}\right)+51 \pi ^4}{48 \pi ^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

The problem to find a closed form for this type of series is related to your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784947/a-ramanujan-type-identity-11-sum-n-1-infty-fracn3e2n-pi-1-16-sum) since holds the following

**Proposition**: Let $\alpha,\beta
 $ be positive numbers such that $\alpha\beta=\pi^{2}
 $. If $n>1
 $ is an integer, then $$\alpha^{n}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{k^{2n-1}}{e^{2\alpha k}-1}-\left(-\beta\right)^{n}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{k^{2n-1}}{e^{2\beta k}-1}=\frac{\left(\alpha^{n}-\left(-\beta\right)^{n}\right)B_{2n}}{4}
 $$ where $B_{2n}
 $ are the Bernoulli numbers (for a proof see [here](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250130041), proposition $2.6$). So for example if we want a closed form of $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{k^{3}}{e^{2^{-1}\pi k}-1}
 $$ we can study the closed form of $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{k^{3}}{e^{8\pi k}-1}.
 $$