# Help Calculation of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^{2n}}{e^k -1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Recently, I read a book :  *Euler, Riemann, Ramanujan - Contact mathematician beyond the space-time* by Nobushige Kurokaw. It says that Ramanujan had found the following formula

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{e^{2k \pi}-1}=\frac{1}{24}-\frac{1}{8\pi}$$

After few month, I succeeded in finding similar formula using Euler-Maclaurin Formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{e^k -1}=\frac{{\pi}^2}{6}-\frac{11}{24}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^{2n-1}}{e^k -1}=\frac{\left| B_{2n}\right|}{4n}((2\pi)^{2n}+(-1)^{n+1}) \quad when \quad n>1$$

I wonder if we can generalize te following formula :

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^{2n}}{e^k -1}$$

I tried with various ways, but I failed. Please answer back users~~~

PS. It's first time that I answer a question on this site. So I could have made some mistakes while writing....

Comment: Do you have a proof for the second series $\sum k/(e^{k} - 1)$? I wonder how it got such a nice closed form.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{e^k -1} \neq \frac{{\pi}^2}{6}-\frac{11}{24}$$
$$\text{RHS} = 1.18660073351489\color{red}{3103139081833312691}$$
$$\text{LHS} = 1.18660073351489\color{red}{2820585500128198498}$$
If you obtained it via Euler-Maclaurin Formula, you might have omitted remainder terms. You might want to experiment these on Mathematica yourself. :)

Comment: Thanks @pisco125 for disproving the identity. The Ramanujan function $P(q)=1-24\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{kq^{k}}{1-q^{k}}$ (which is related to the series in question) has a known closed form when $q=\pm e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}} $ for positive rational $n$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh   I was a bit skeptical when I first saw this identity by OP. Because if it were true, then there would be no reason that Ramanujan did not notice it. I have seen the close form $e^{-\pi}$ and $e^{-\sqrt{2}\pi}$, are they related elliptic singular values? Does one of Ramanujan's notebook contain information about them? I am also very curious about these sums.

Comment: @pisco125: yes they are related to elliptic singular values. The function $P(q) $ can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals as $$P(q) =\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{6E}{K}+k^{2}-5\right)$$

Comment: The sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i^{n}q^{i}/(1-q^{i})$ can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals if $n$ is odd. For even values of $n$ there is no known closed form.

Comment: Also see this answer to a related question : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944103/72031

Comment: Thanks everyone for repling my question. I'm just 17 years old, and I have no one to ask it in my school. As @ParamanandSingh mentioned, it seems that I omitted the remainder terms which is quite a serious problem.... I've learned some precious infromation today.. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

CAS says:

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{k^{2 n}}{\exp (k)-1}=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } k^{2 n} \exp (-j k)\right)=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty }
   \text{Li}_{-2 n}\left(e^{-j}\right)=-\psi _e^{(2 n)}(1)$$

where:

$\text{Li}_{-2 n}\left(e^{-j}\right)$ is the polylogarithm function,

$\psi _e^{(2 n)}(1)$ is the n-th derivative of the [q-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html).

**Mathematica code:**

`Sum[k^(2 n)/(Exp[k] - 1), {k, 1, Infinity}] == -QPolyGamma[2 n, 1, E]`

where `E` is the exponential constant.