# Computing Eisenstein series terms

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms

I have to compute a few terms of the normalized Eisenstein series: $\xi = e^{2 \pi i \tau}$, where $\tau$ belongs to the upper-half plane. In particular, I have to show that:

$$ E_{4} (\tau) =1+240(\xi + ... \xi^{2} + ... \xi^{3}..) = \frac{s_{4}(1,\tau)}{2 \zeta(4)}$$

$$ E_{8} (\tau) =1+(\xi + ... \xi^{2} + ... \xi^{3}..) = \frac{s_{8}(1,\tau)}{2 \zeta(8)}$  $$

then it asks me to conjecture some relation between these two functions("modular forms").

I'm not sure what the $s_{n}(1,\tau)$ functions represent in this case, but the $E_{n}(\tau)$ function comes from the alternate notation when dealing with the $q$-expansion of the Eisenstein series. At least, that is what I understood from this wikipedia link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series

My lecturer has not clarified any of these issues and it is not even covered in the textbook that I'm using. Hence, I would very much appreciate some help in trying to figure out this problem.

Comment: I think that here $s_n(\sigma,\tau)$ is the “original” Eisenstein series for complex numbers linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$, ie $s_n(\sigma,\tau)=\sum_{(c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \backslash \{(0,0)\}}{(c\tau+d\sigma)^{-k}}$.

Comment: You may have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3708157/72031).