# Analogs of $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{13}}{e^{2\pi n}-1}=\frac{1}{24}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

**Context:**

As I and others were able to show in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557171/on-proving-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracn13e2-pi-n-1-frac-124/4086092#4086092), we have that
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{13}}{e^{2\pi n}-1}=\frac{1}{24}.$$
In my answer, I let $$E_{2k}(\tau)=1+c_{2k}\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{2k-1}q^n}{1-q^n},$$
with $\tau\in\Bbb H$ and $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$ and $c_{2k}=\frac{(2\pi i)^{2k}}{(2k-1)!\zeta(2k)}$, be the Eisenstein series of weight $2k$, where $k\in\Bbb Z_{>2}$. Using the well known property that $$E_{2k}(-1/\tau)=\tau^{2k}E_{2k}(\tau),\tag1$$
it is easy to see that
$$S_{2k-1}(e^{2i\pi/\tau})-\tau^{2k}S_{2k-1}(e^{-2i\pi\tau})=\frac{\tau^{2k}-1}{c_{2k}},\tag 2$$
where $$S_{\ell}(q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^\ell}{q^n-1},$$
since $$E_{2k}(\tau)=1+c_{2k}S_{2k-1}(e^{-2i\pi\tau}).\tag3$$
Using the values $k=7$ and $\tau=i$ in $(2)$, we get
$$S_{13}(e^{2\pi})-i^{14}S_{13}(e^{2\pi})=\frac{i^{14}-1}{c_{14}},$$
which reduces to
$$S_{13}(e^{2\pi})=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{13}}{e^{2\pi n}-1}=\frac{1}{24}.$$

**My Problem:**

I am trying to find identities analogous to $S_{13}(e^{2\pi})=1/24$ using the same general method.

It is well known that $(1)$ is a the special case of
$$E_{2k}\left(\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}\right)=(c\tau+d)^{2k}E_{2k}(\tau),\tag4$$ corresponding to the choice
$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. The formula $(4)$ is true for all $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in\text{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$.

I was hoping of using $(4)$ instead of $(1)$ to generate identities analogous to the one in the title of this question. To this end, I denote $\gamma=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ and $\gamma(\tau)=\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}$. Then using $(3)$, we have
$$S_{2k-1}(e^{-2i\pi\gamma(\tau)})-(c\tau+d)^{2k}S_{2k-1}(e^{-2i\pi\tau})=\frac{(c\tau+d)^{2k}-1}{c_{2k}}.$$
Then suppose we find $\tau\in\Bbb H$ such that $\gamma(\tau)=\tau$. This would give $S_{2k-1}(e^{-2i\pi\gamma(\tau)})=S_{2k-1}(e^{-2i\pi\tau})$ and thus
$$S_{2k-1}(e^{-2i\pi\tau})=-\frac{1}{c_{2k}}.\tag{*}$$
There is an infinite family for such $\tau\in\Bbb H$, each corresponding to a unique element of $\text{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$. Using these I am able to find things like
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{13}}{\zeta^ne^{n\pi\sqrt3/7}-1}=\frac1{24},\qquad \zeta=(-1)^{-5/7}, \gamma=\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 1 \\ -7 & 3\end{pmatrix},\tag5$$
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{13}}{\zeta^ne^{2n\pi/5}-1}=\frac{1}{24},\qquad \zeta=(-1)^{-2/5},\gamma=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ -5 & -2\end{pmatrix},\tag6$$
and others.

NOTE: I am unable to numerically test identities $(5),(6)$ because I only have desmos, which doesn't do complex numbers. So I am relying on the theory which I have laid out.

**My Question:**

The keen among you may have noticed that the formula $(*)$ does not hold for all values of $k\in\Bbb Z_{>2}$. Indeed, we have all the values listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4220424/583016) which show that the values of $S_{2k-1}(e^{-2i\pi\tau})$ for certain fixed $\tau$ differ from $-1/c_{2k}$ for certain values of $k$ but not for others.

My question is, why does this happen.

For example, if we plug in $k=6$ and $\tau=\frac{1+i\sqrt3}{2}$ into $(*)$ we should get
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{11}}{(-1)^ne^{n\pi\sqrt3}-1}=-\frac{691}{65520},$$
but actually,
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{11}}{(-1)^ne^{n\pi\sqrt3}-1}=\frac{189\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{4}  \right )^{24} }{272629760\pi^{18}}-\frac{691}{65520}.$$
Why does this happen? Where does that $\Gamma$ term come from? Why doesn't $(*)$ work for all $k\in\Bbb Z_{>2}$ and $\gamma\in\text{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$ when there is a solution $z=\tau\in\Bbb H$ to $\gamma(z)=z$? I figure it has something to do with elliptic curves and elliptic integrals, but I don't know enough of the theory to see it.

Comment: $\gamma(\tau)= \tau$ means that $\tau$ is an elliptic point, the only ones are in $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})i, SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\zeta_3$ so you won't reach many interesting particular values of modular forms this way.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944103/72031

Comment: Your last sum can be evaluated using the function $f(q) =\sum\frac{n^{11}q^ n} {1-q^n}$ which Ramanujan expressed in terms of his functions $P, Q, R$ as $691+65520f(q)=441Q^3+250R^2$. Explicit evaluations of $P, Q, R$ involve elliptic integrals and moduli and the appearance of $\Gamma(1/4)$ is due to that.

Comment: Btw one should have $\Gamma (1/3)$ instead of $\Gamma (1/4)$.

Answer (score 5):

I believe equation $(*)$ breaks down since the formula cannot hold whenever $c\tau+d$ is a $2k$th root of unity; otherwise you will be dividing both sides by $(c\tau+d)^{2k}-1=0$.

In your example you have $\tau=(1+i\sqrt3)/2$ and $k=6$ so we have $a-d=1$, $b=-1$ and $c=1$. For the matrix to have unit determinant, we must have $d=0,-1$.

If $d=0$ then we have $(c\tau+d)^{2k}-1=(e^{i\pi/3})^{12}-1=0$.

If $d=-1$ then we have $(c\tau+d)^{2k}-1=(-e^{-i\pi/3})^{12}-1=0$.

Both cases mean the identity does not follow.

By the same argument this can be extended to [your linked list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943244/on-the-general-form-of-the-family-sum-n-1-infty-fracnke2n-pi-1/4220424#4220424) to understand that series of the form $$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{4k-1}}{e^{2\pi n}-1},\quad\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{n^{6k-1}}{(-1)^ne^{n\pi\sqrt3}-1},\cdots$$ do not obey the pattern. I think $\Gamma(\cdot)$ appears due to the particular values of the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html).

Comment: This helps, thank you (+1). Would you happen to know how to evaluate $S_{2k-1}(e^{-2i\pi\tau})$ when $(c\tau+d)^{2k}=1$? How does it relate to elliptic integrals?

Answer (score 1):

The Eisenstein series $E_{2k}$ can be expressed as polynomials in $E_4,E_6$ with rational coefficients for $k\geq 2$. I have discussed this using Ramanujan's approach in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944103/72031).

Some of these polynomials have $E_4$ as a factor and some others have $E_6$ as a factor. So knowing zeroes of $E_4,E_6$ does our job. You should prove that $E_4$ vanishes at $\tau=(-1+i(\sqrt{3})^{\pm 1})/2$ and $E_6$ vanishes at $i, (-2+i)/4$.

In particular this allows us to evaluate the sums involving $e^{2n\pi},(-e^{\pi})^n,(-e^{\pi\sqrt{3} })^n$ in closed form.

Also the expression of $E_4,E_6$ in terms of elliptic integrals and moduli is necessary to get a closed form for the cases when $E_{2k}\neq 0$.

Further note that $E_4,E_6$ can be evaluated in closed form using gamma function values if $\tau$ is a root of a quadratic equation with rational coefficients.