# How to bound $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{4k-1}}{e^{2\pi n}-1}$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

By using this answer ([On proving that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{13}}{e^{2\pi n}-1}=\frac 1{24}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3557171/on-proving-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracn13e2-pi-n-1-frac-124)), I found that
$$2\frac{1-2^{-4k-2}}{1-2^{-4k-1}}\frac{(4k+2)!}{(2\pi)^{4k+2}(8k+4)}\lt \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{4k+1}}{e^{2\pi n}-1}\lt \frac{2}{1-2^{-4k-1}}\frac{(4k+2)!}{(2\pi)^{4k+2}(8k+4)}$$
where $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Are there some known bounds (useful for approximations) for the similar series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{4k-1}}{e^{2\pi n}-1}$$
where $k\in\mathbb{N}$?