# Sum of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{3 n^5 \left(6596 n^8+924 n^4-2856\right)}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I see a puzzle in the picture below.
[image]

It seems that the sum
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{3 n^5 \left(6596 n^8+924 n^4-2856\right)}{e^{2 \pi  n}-1}$$
is an integer and can form a date.
However, even Mathematica cannot give a precise result. The partial sum suggests the result might be **818**. How to calculate it?

Comment: Why was this downvoted to -4?

Comment: Interestingly, $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{3n^5 (2856)}{e^{2 \pi n} - 1} \approx 17$$ [seems to be](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B3Power%5Bn%2C5%5D%5C%2840%292856%5C%2841%29%2CPower%5Be%2C2%CF%80n%5D-1%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D) an integer as well.

Comment: In fact, it seems that \begin{align*} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{3n^5 (6596n^8)}{e^{2 \pi n} - 1} &\approx 824.5, \\ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{3n^5 (924n^4)}{e^{2 \pi n} - 1} &\approx 10.5, \\ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{3n^5 (2856)}{e^{2 \pi n} - 1} &\approx 17. \end{align*}  I suspect that there is a way to calculate $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{e^{2 \pi n} - 1},$$ resulting in rational numbers.

Comment: @L.F. I was about typing the same. It seems to be true for 100 decimals

Comment: @L.F. Have a look at my edit

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943244/on-the-general-form-of-the-family-sum-n-1-infty-fracnke2n-pi-1?noredirect=1) helps.

Answer (score 1):

If $$a_n=\frac{3 n^5 \left(6596 n^8+924 n^4-2856\right)}{e^{2 \pi n}-1}$$ the ratio test
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{e^{2 \pi  n}-1}{e^{2 \pi  (n+1)}-1}\Bigg[1+\frac{13}{n}+\frac{78}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\Bigg]\sim e^{-2 \pi }$$ shows an extrely fast convergence.

If we consider
$$b_n=\frac{3 n^5 \left(6596 n^8+924 n^4-2856\right)}{e^{2 \pi n}} < a_n$$ we can explicitely compute the infinite sum since
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {n^k}{e^{2 \pi n}}=\text{Li}_{-k}\left(e^{-2 \pi }\right)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=\frac{24 x}{(x-1)^{14}} P_{12}(x)$$ where $x=e^{2\pi}$. I shall not type here the polynomial of degree $12$ in $x$ (just because of the size of the coefficients (the smallest is $583$ but the largest is $1875908773452$; their mean is $394936819200$).

Numerically
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=817.9491271\cdots$$  Now, consider
$$\frac{1}{e^{2 \pi  n}-1 }=\sum_{q=0}^\infty e^{-2 \pi  (q+1) n}$$ and
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^k e^{-2 \pi  n (q+1)}=\text{Li}_{-k}\left(e^{-2 \pi  (q+1)}\right)$$

Now, the computation of the partial sums
$$S_r=\sum_{n=1}^r a_n$$ becomes simple
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 r & S_r \\
 5  & 817.98888429499578340114316254727116027126495 \\
 10 & 817.99999999999933816348471123533611149002402 \\
 15 & 817.99999999999999999999999804247971649003791 \\
 20 & 817.99999999999999999999999999999999999847618 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Computing
$$S_{100}=818-5.616\times 10^{-246}$$
$$S_{1000}=818-6.628\times 10^{-2689}$$

$818$ is the asymptotoic limit of the summation (it will never reach it).

**Edit**

It *seems* that I have been $\large\color{red}{\text{wrong}}$. Using Mathematica, type

`S[p_]:=NSum[(3*n^5*(-2856 + 924*n^4 + 6596*n^8))/(-1 + E^(2*n*Pi)), {n, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> p+3,PrecisionGoal -> p+3, AccuracyGoal -> p+3, NSumTerms -> p]`

The result is always $818.$ followed by $p$ trailing $0$'s.