# Is this a new representation of (some) Bernoulli numbers?

Tags: divisor-sum, bernoulli-numbers, oeis

Let $\operatorname{B}(n)$ denote the Bernoulli numbers and
$\operatorname{b}(n) = \operatorname{B}(n)/n$ with $b(0)=1$
the divided Bernoulli numbers. Also let $\sigma_{k}(n)= \sum_{d \mid n} d^k$
denote the sum of the $k$-th powers of the positive divisors of $n$.

Recently Simon Plouffe made the following conjecture in OEIS [A013965](https://oeis.org/A013965):

$$  \sum_{j \ge 1} \frac{\sigma_{17}(j)}{\exp(2 \pi j)}  
    \, = \, \frac{43867}{28728} 
    \, = \, \frac{\operatorname{B}(18)}{36} .
$$

Plouffe found similar relations earlier, but without mentioning the connection
with the Bernoulli numbers, for example in [A001160](https://oeis.org/A001160)
and [A013961](https://oeis.org/A013961).

Vaclav Kotesovec generalized these observations in [A362870](https://oeis.org/A362870) with the following far-reaching conjecture:

If $\nu$ is twice an odd number greater than 1
(i.e., $\nu = 4n+2$, a term of [A016825](https://oeis.org/A016825) that is greater than 2), then

$$ \operatorname{b}(\nu) = \frac{\operatorname{B}(\nu)}{\nu} 
    \, = \, 2 \sum_{j \ge 1} \frac{\sigma_{\nu-1}(j)} { \exp(2 \pi j)} 
    \, = \, \frac{A358625(\nu)}{A075180(\nu - 1)}.
$$

We numerically checked the first 50 terms $\nu > 2$ of A016825. They suggest the
plausibility of the conjecture.
Although it becomes increasingly challenging for larger values to achieve
satisfactory accuracy, we gained in this range at least agreement in the
first 800 decimal places.

Does anyone know a proof or can give references to relevant literature?

**Edit:** From Raymond Manzoni's answer and the literature he cites
it is clear that the formulas quoted above are not conjectures
but proven facts.
A detailed presentation of the theory and a proof of Ramanujan's theorem can be found in:

Bruce C. Berndt, Analytic Eisenstein series, theta functions,
and series relations in the spirit of Ramanujan. J. Reine Angew. Math.,
303/304:332–365, 1978. (See Corollary 5.10, p.355).

Comment: For those of us who are less familiar with such things: what are the reasons one might make this conjecture about $\sum \sigma_k(j) / exp(2\pi j)$? Given the expression, I can certainly see evaluating it numerically and observing it to be rational. But _why_ would one come to that expression to begin with?

I expect that any proof of the identity would shed some light on the significance of the sum. But given that it's only conjecture, *why* would one come to that conjecture to begin with?

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944103/72031

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simon Plouffe proposed in this [$2003$ article](https://vixra.org/pdf/1409.0055v1.pdf) (and in his answer here) this formula implicit in Ramanujan's work :
$$\frac {B_{4n+2}}{8n+4}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {k^{4n+1}}{e^{\,2k\pi}-1}$$

According to Bruce Berndt in ["Ramanujan's Notebooks part V" p.$427$](https://books.google.com/books?id=O8XcBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA421) (see too his $1977$ paper ["Modular transformations and generalizations of several formulae of Ramanujan"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-7/issue-1/Modular-transformations-and-generalizations-of-several-formulae-of-Ramanujan/10.1216/RMJ-1977-7-1-147.full) ) this formula was proved first by Glaisher in $1889$ although established by Hurwitz in $1881$ in his thesis.
Other interesting generalizations may be found in Vepsas ["On Plouffe's Ramanujan Identities"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609775) and Bagis ["Evaluations of Series Related to Jacobi Elliptic Functions"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09445) as well as Zucker's ["The Summation of Series of Hyperbolic Functions"](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0510019?journalCode=sjmaah) and others (for people hoping to generalize this for other values of $\zeta$...).

Following Lambert series is a generating function for the [$\sigma_a$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) :
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^a q^k}{1-q^k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty k^a q^{j\,k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty q^k \sigma_a(k)$$

Use $\,a=4n+1$ and $\,q=e^{-2\pi}\,$ to conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much, Raymond. So this seems to be a pretty standard result (Hurwitz/Glaisher/Berndt applied to Lambert series for sigma) and labels like 'conjecture' or 'empirical' on OEIS can be safely removed from the related identities as they are misleading at best. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Glad it helped @PeterLuschny. I added references for the neat $\frac {B_{4n+2}}{8n+4}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {k^{4n+1}}{e^{\,2k\pi}-1}$ because this formula is rather old but not so easy to find except in Simon Plouffe's work. The Lambert series derivation at the end appears in Hardy&Wright §17.10 and is classical in number theory. Thanks too for the opportunity of having Simon Plouffe here with links to very nice subjects!

Comment: So who is the author of the first formula? Ramanujan was born in 1887...

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec : The references provided by Berndt are :
- Glaisher "On the series which represent the twelve elliptic and four zeta functions" Mess. Math. 18 (1889), 1-84 [here](https://archive.org/details/messengermathem05glaigoog/page/n8/mode/2up) for a proof  
- Hurwitz (in 1881 in his thesis) references
[1] Grundlagen einer independenten Theorie der elliptischen Modu1funktionen und Theorie der Multiplikator-Gleichungen erster Stufe, Math. Ann. 18 (1881), 528-592.
[2] Mathematische Werke, Band I 
(paywall [here](https://archive.org/search?query=messenger+of+mathematics+1889) )

Comment: rather [here](https://archive.org/search?query=Hurwitz+Mathematische+Werke) and possibly free [here](https://archive.org/details/sim_mathematische-annalen_1881_18/page/528/mode/2up) (I didn't read these papers...)

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec: Ramanujan proved a general formula (in terms of recurrence relation) for sums of type $S_r(q) =-\frac{B_{r+1}}{2(r+1)}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^rq^n}{1-q^n}$ and the first formula listed in this answer is an immediate consequence when one puts $q=e^{-2\pi}$. See details at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944103/72031 Ramanujan's technique gives closed form evaluation for $r=4m+3$ also.

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of connections with those sums and Bernoulli numbers. That result I published on the OEIS about A013965, A001160 and A013961 is not isolated.
You can see others like that here: https://vixra.org/pdf/2305.0022v2.pdf. There are 659 other results in the same vein. Most of those are not yet published on the OEIS.

Now about the function sigma and related sums: there are other results also but this time connected to prime numbers and the Eisenstein series here: https://vixra.org/pdf/2304.0180v2.pdf.

These were inspired by a finding from Ramanujan about Bernoulli numbers and this sum :

$$ \sum_{n>=1}\ \frac{n^{4 k+1}}{\exp(2 \pi n) - 1} = \frac{\operatorname{Bernoulli}(4 k+2)}{2(4k+2)}$$
I extended the finding to other sums.
Does this put some light on these sums ?
Best regards,
Simon Plouffe

Comment: I added a several more conjectures today, see https://oeis.org/A014103. All of them are verified to match 10000 decimals.