# The Double Basel Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, harmonic-numbers

I have been playing with the series which I had been calling the 'Double Basel problem' for the past couple of hours
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{{n^2 +m^2}}.
$$
After wrestling with this for awhile, I managed to generalize a result demonstrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYc9ManKC-s). This identity is:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+m^2} = \frac{1}{2x}\left[ \pi \coth{\pi x} - \frac{1}{x}\right].
$$
Hence the original series becomes:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n}\left[\pi \coth{\pi n} - \frac{1}{n} \right].
$$

I have no idea where to go next with this problem.  I seriously doubt that this series is convergent; however, I have been unable to prove it.

1. Can you prove that this series is divergent?
2. If it converges what is its value?

Thanks so much!

Comment: For large $n$, $\coth(n \pi) \sim 1$ so the first term behaves like $1/n$ which diverges. More precisely, $\coth(n \pi)/n >1/n$ for $n>0$

Comment: Inasmuch as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\coth(\pi n)=1$, then the series of interest diverges.

Comment: The series can be made more interesting by adding a factor $(-1)^n$ to get $\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{m^2+ n^2}$ which is convergent and has a nice closed form.

Comment: Could you link to this series? I would love to see the closed form!  Thanks.

Comment: The sum in my previous comment can be evaluated using the approach in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2482542/72031)

Comment: Also see this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4113092/72031

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The series is monotonic in each argument, hence can be bounded below by an integral, of the form:

$$\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dxdy=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{r^2}rdrd\theta=\infty,$$

so the series diverges.

Comment: Slick answer 

Comment: Thanks for this, but the area you are integrating over isn't well preserved in the polar coordinates.  Is the divergence still true?

Comment: @guavas222 Changing variable can't turn a divergent integral into a convergent one if the integrand is nonnegative.

Comment: @guavas222: You can fix that by adapting the limits so you're sure you're integrating over a _smaller_ set to the right: $$\int_1^\infty \int_1^\infty \frac{dxdy}{x^2+y^2} \ge \int_3^\infty \int_{\pi/8}^{3\pi/8} \frac{rd\theta dr}{r^2} = \infty $$

Answer (score 5):

Another proof that the series diverges:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{{n^2 +m^2}} \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{{n^2 +m^2}} \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{{n^2 +n^2}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2n} = \infty.
$$

Comment: (+1) As short as [my approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2560001)

Answer (score 2):

Less slick answer: Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\coth(x)=1$ and since $\coth(x)\geq 1$ for $x\geq 0,$ then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n}\left[\pi - \frac{1}{n} \right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{2n}-\frac{\pi}{2n^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n}\left[\pi \coth{\pi n} - \frac{1}{n} \right],$$ and so the series diverges as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{2n}$ is divergent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\pi}{2n^2}=\frac{\pi^3}{12}.$