# The Double Basel Problem Revisited

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Earlier I had asked a question about the series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{{n^2 +m^2}}.
$$
Which looks like some kind of double series version of the Basel problem.  Much to my disappointment this series was shown to diverge here ([The Double Basel Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180416/the-double-basel-problem)).  There could still be a series worthy of being called the Double Basel Problem.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{{(n^2 +m^2)^2}}.
$$
This double series is certainly convergent; however evaluating the sum involves tackling some series I have never seen before.   Using the same kind of trick from the other problem and differentiating, this double series can be reduced into:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^2}{4n^2} {csch}^2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{4n^3} \coth \pi n - \frac{1}{2n^4}
$$

Has anyone seen series like the first two?
How do we even begin to make progress on this kind of thing?

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/197496 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1108246.