# Evaluate the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}-1)} $.

Tags: sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

In Ramanujan's Notebooks Volume 2 by B.C. Berndt I came across the formula
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}-1)} = \log 2 + \frac{3}{4} \log \pi - \frac{\pi}{12} -\log \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4} \right). $$
The proof provided uses some special values from the theory of elliptic functions, but I am unfamiliar with the subject. Does there exist a different evaluation of the series? I tried contour integration, cotangent partial fraction, and applying Poisson summation or converting to an integral but so far no success. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/
 I found [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h383533p2127337)

Comment: See this :https://math.stackexchange.com/q/938123/72031

Comment: See as well the generalization [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1944741/)

Comment: Theta functions and elliptic integrals are the key here, but maybe some Mellin transform expert can also help here.

Comment: Thanks for the links everyone but all of these methods use the theory of elliptic/theta functions. For example the value $\theta(e^{-\pi}) = \frac{2}{\pi} K(\frac{1}{2}) $ is used, or converting the series to a Dedekind eta function evaluation, etc. Is there any way to evaluate the sum without using elliptic/theta functions? (I am not familiar with that theory)

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}-1)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-2 \pi  (k+1) n}}{n}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-2 \pi  (k+1) n}}{n}=\log \left(1-e^{-2 \pi  (k+1)}\right)$$ So, now, you need to compute
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \log \left(1-e^{-2 \pi  (k+1)}\right)$$ and this is explained in the link provided by @Jean-Marie.