# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, closed-form

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115477/evaluate-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1ne2-pi-n-1?noredirect=1) question, there's a quite simple closed form mentioned for the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}-1)}$$

However I'm wondering if there exists any simple closed form known for the series of type

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{\pi n}+1)}, \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}+1)},\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{(2k+1)n\pi }+1)},\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(e^{(2k)n\pi}+1)}$$

I've been thinking about thee kinds of series from quite some time and so far
I have tried contour integration, cotangent partial fraction, and applying Poisson summation or converting to an integral but so far no success. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @pisco Of course a natural number.

Comment: @pisco Fixed, thanks

Comment: I think the first sum is equal to $$\frac{\pi}{8}+\ln\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{9}{8}\ln2-\frac{3}{4}\ln \pi$$ See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281%2F%28n%28e%5E%7BPi+n%7D%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfnity%7D%29-%28Pi%2F8%2Bln%28Gamma%281%2F4%29%29-%289%2F8%29ln%282%29-3%2F4+ln%28Pi%29%29

Comment: All your four sums can be expressed in $\pi, \Gamma(1/4)$ and some algebraic numbers (depending on $k$), it will be more complicated as $k$ increases.

Comment: And you get the second sum here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281%2F%28n%28e%5E%7B2Pi+n%7D%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfnity%7D%29-%28Pi%2F4%2Bln%28Gamma%281%2F4%29%29-%287%2F4%29ln%282%29-3%2F4+ln%28Pi%29%29

Comment: All these sums can be easily handled using the theory of theta functions and elliptic integrals. Consider $f(q) =\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{q^{2n}}{n(1-q^{2n})}$. Then you can express all these sums in terms of $f(e^{-\pi}) $.

Comment: For the first sum just note that it equals $f(q^{1/2})-2f(q)$ and the second sum is $f(q) - 2f(q^2)$.

Comment: Similarly you can express the more general sums at the end of your question as $f(q^{k/2})-2f(q^k)$ where $k$ is a positive integer.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/938644/72031) which evaluates $f(q) $ in a closed form.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Can you prove that the first and the second sum equal what wolfram has provided?

Comment: Yes, that should not be difficult given my linked answer. The sum mentioned by @OmranKouba is specifically $a(q) - 2a(q^2)$ where the values of $a(q), a(q^2)$ are given in my linked answer. Perform the calculations and you should get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

With help of Mathematica I have:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n \left(e^{a n \pi }-1\right) }=\\\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-a n m \pi }}{n}\right)=\\\sum
   _{m=1}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-a n m \pi }}{n}\right)=\\\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } -\ln \left(1-e^{-a m \pi }\right)=\\-\frac{1}{24} (a \pi
   )-\ln \left(\eta \left(\frac{i a}{2}\right)\right)$$
and
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n (\exp (a \pi  n)+1)}=\frac{a \pi }{8}-\ln \left(\eta \left(\frac{i a}{2}\right)\right)+2 \ln (\eta (i a))$$

where $a>0$ and $\eta \left(\frac{i a}{2}\right)$ is: **Dedekind eta modular elliptic function.**

MMA code:

`Sum[1/(n*(Exp[a Pi n] - 1)), {n, 1, Infinity}] == -((a \[Pi])/24) -  Log[DedekindEta[(I a)/2]]`

`Sum[1/(n*(Exp[a Pi n] + 1)), {n, 1, Infinity}] == (a \[Pi])/8 -  Log[DedekindEta[(I a)/2]] + 2 Log[DedekindEta[I a]]`

Comment: Luckily the values of $\eta(ia) $ for many integer values of $a$ are already calculated on mathse:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101157/72031