# Reference request for a formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function, ramanujan-summation

In equation $6.6$ pg. $20$ of https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318529311_Some_infinite_series_involving_hyperbolic_functions we have a nice expression
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(e^{2\pi n}-1)}=\frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)-\frac{\pi}{12}+\log \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right) $$
**Question:** I have searched the above referenced book but could not find a proof of the above formula. Can someone please prove it or give a reference (with page number) of it?

Comment: Have you searched the formula on [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn(e%5E%7B2%5Cpi%20n%7D-1)%7D%24&p=1)? [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115477/evaluate-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1ne2-pi-n-1?noredirect=1).

Comment: @nejimban Thank you. But for a proof, Can you please give a reference of a book? Or a proof please?

Comment: The second link refers to “Ramanujan's Notebooks Volume 2 by B.C. Berndt”. The proof for the formula apparently uses the theory of elliptic functions, of which I am not familiar. I do not know of any other proof, but hopefully the first link (approach0) points at other references.

Comment: @nejimban Okay. Thanks a lot