# finite expression for this lambert series??

Tags: sequences-and-series

given the Lambert series

$$ f(q)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{r}\frac{q^{n}}{1-q^{n}} $$

for an real number 'r'

is there a closed form or a soution of this in terms of a differential or integral equation ?

Comment: [see the second sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series#Examples) which is not simple at all

Comment: If $r$ is a positive odd integer or $r = -1$ then it has a closed form in terms of elliptic integral $K$ and modulus $k$. I don't know what happens when $r$ takes other values. Such sums were studied in detail by Ramanujan in his classic paper *On certain arithmetical functions*. see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1944103/72031 for odd positive $r$ and for $r =-1$ see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/938644/72031